# Sending ArrayList<Object> POST request with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to send something like this to server

```
{
  "InoorPersonID": "",
  "Discount": 0,
  "DiscountDescription": "",
  "Description": "",
  "OrderDetailList": [
    {
      "ProductID": 0,
      "Amount": 0
    }
  ],
  "ClientId": "",
  "ClientSecret": ""
}
```

and this is my service interface

```
public interface StoreRetrofitSalesService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(ServiceUrl.URL_ORDER_SET)
    Call<ServiceResult<Integer>> orderSet(@Field("OrderDetailList") ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderDetails,
                                          @Field("Discount") String discount,
                                          @Field("ClientId") String clientId,
                                          @Field("ClientSecret") String clientSecret,
                                          @Field("Description") String description,
                                          @Field("InoorPersonID") String inoorPersonId,
                                          @Field("DiscountDescription") String discountDescription);

}
```

The logcat show this

```
OrderDetailList=org.crcis.noorreader.store.OrderDetail%408208296&Discount=0&...
```

I have two question:

1. Why OrderDetailList can't convert to JSON.
2. How can I use @FieldMap for this params.
   I recently test `Map<String, Object>` but it returns same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use GSON

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Create a model for your data like this

```
public class Order {

    @SerializedName("InoorPersonID")
    String inoorPersonId;
    @SerializedName("Discount")
    int discount;
    @SerializedName("DiscountDescription")
    String discountDescription;
    @SerializedName("Description")
    String description;
    @SerializedName("OrderDetailList")
    ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderDetailList;
    @SerializedName("ClientId")
    String clientId;
    @SerializedName("ClientSecret")
    String clientSecret;

    //Don't forget to create/generate the getter and setter
}
```

And change your Service to

```
public interface StoreRetrofitSalesService {

    @POST(ServiceUrl.URL_ORDER_SET)
    Call<ServiceResult<Integer>> orderSet(@Body Order order);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. great. it works. but I want to know if I can use @FieldMap instead of creating new class Order? Because all of my service methods accept FieldMap, I just want to have same params for all.

Comment: @MojtabaMahamed Hmmm I don't think so because if you use Fieldmap it will create a url encoded param, if you want to sent a dynamic parameter I recommend you to send it by JSON format via POST body like what I write in the answer.

Comment: @Niko Yuwono, how to use this with mulipart partmap with retrofit 2 without using model??

Comment: @TheGreat004 Why do you want to do that? maybe you can try asking a new question.

Comment: @NikoYuwono, there is already a lot of model classes and i don't want to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks @NikoAdrianusYuwono. You save my day. I've big troubles using `@FormUrlEncoded` with `@FieldMap`. Using this way everything works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277777/sending-an-array-in-request-body-is-not-working-using-retrofit-2-1-0 using the same but still facing the issue