# How to POST ArrayList <Object> with Retrofit?

Tags: java, post, retrofit2

I want to send something like this to server

```
{
      "tourId": 5,
      "stopPoints": [
          {
              "arrivalAt": 15532956000,
              "lat": 10.826125820975317,
              "leaveAt": 1553299200000,
              "long": 106.68923623859882,
              "maxCost": 100000,
              "minCost": 50000,
              "name": "Bun new",
              "serviceTypeId": 1
          },
          {
              "arrivalAt": 15532956011,
              "lat": 13.826125820975317,
              "leaveAt": 1553299200000,
              "long": 100.68923623859882,
              "maxCost": 150000,
              "minCost": 10000,
              "name": "Bun update",
              "serviceTypeId": 1
          },
       ],

}
```

this is my service interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("tour/set-stop-points")
    Call<serviceStopPoints> stopPointsSet(@Body serviceStopPoints serviceStopPoints);
```

This is stopPoint class

```
public class stopPoint {
    @SerializedName("arrivalAt")
    @Expose
    private long arrivalAt;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private double lat;
    @SerializedName("leaveAt")
    @Expose
    private long leaveAt;
    @SerializedName("long")
    @Expose
    private double lng;
    @SerializedName("maxCost")
    @Expose
    private long maxCost;
    @SerializedName("minCost")
    @Expose
    private long minCost;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("serviceTypeId")
    @Expose
    private int serviceTypeId;
}
```

and this is serviceStopPoints class

```
public class serviceStopPoints extends Number {
    @SerializedName("tourId")
    @Expose
        String tourID;
    @SerializedName("stopPoints")
    @Expose
    ArrayList<stopPoint> stopPoints;
}
```

i have read this link and try it
[Sending ArrayList<Object> POST request with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389753/sending-arraylistobject-post-request-with-retrofit) 
but i don't understand this line

```
 Call<ServiceResult<Integer>> orderSet(@Body Order order);
```

Please help me to send this ArrayList with Retrofit.
Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add get/set to your class and
create your request object.

```
serviceStopPoints request = new serviceStopPoints();
List<stopPoint> stopPointList = new ArrayList<stopPoint>();
stopPoint s = new stopPoint();
s.setArrivalAt("..");
.
.
.
stopPointList.add(s);
request.setTourID("1234);
request.setStopPoints(stopPointList);
```

Usage

```
 ApiHelper.getService().stopPointsSet(request).enqueue(new Callback<serviceStopPoints>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<serviceStopPoints> call, Response<serviceStopPoints> response) {
                //do with the response
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<serviceStopPoints> call, Throwable t) {
               //error
            }
        });
```

I think you do not need @FromUrlEncoded.

HOPE THIS HELP :)

Answer (score 0):

this is my code, but it doesn't work, do you know what's wrong with it

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("url")
                .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<serviceStopPoints> call = api.stopPointsSet(serviceStopPoint);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<serviceStopPoints>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<serviceStopPoints> call, Response<serviceStopPoints> response) {
//do sth

}
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<serviceStopPoints> call, Throwable t) {

            }


        });
```